What is the correct way to show a many-to-many entity relationship using an associative table?
I'm reviewing a data model diagram at work that looks something like this and I can't tell if this is supposed to be a many-to-many relationship. The diagram author included a legend that says the line + circle symbol means "one-to-one (unidirectional)" but I don't think that is what it actually means because it should mean "zero or one".
If interpreted using the correct symbol definitions, this would be read as: one or many Foo records can be associated with a zero or one Bar records.
If using the author's definition, this would be read as: one or many Foo records are associated with a Bar record.
Either way, does it make sense to have an associative mapping table for this depicted relationship? My understanding is that these are for many-to-many relationships and not many-to-one.
Note that Foo_Bar_Mapping doesn't have any other attributes and the domain entities that Foo and Bar represent don't appear to have any logical constraints that would preclude them from referencing each other.

